# Как скопировать void* (C++) в byte[] (C#) (CLI)?

Tags: c#, c++

У меня есть `byte[]` на стороне C# который мне нужно передать в CLI метод и там в него скопировать данные из `void*`

Делаю это так

C#

```
byte[] copy;
m_Logic.CopyToArray(out copy);
//There is filled `copy` that I can use
```

C++ (CLI)

```
    void Agent_CLI::CopyToArray([Out] array<unsigned char> ^% input)
    {
        std::vector<int> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        void * data_to_copy = data.data(); //TEST : my data to copy

        int data_size = (int)data.size();
        input = gcnew array<unsigned char>(data_size);
        memcpy(&input[0], data_to_copy, data_size * sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
```

но получаю вот такую ошибку

> error C2664: 'void *memcpy(void *,const void *,::size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr' to 'void *'

что не так?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-marshal-arrays-using-cpp-interop?view=msvc-160

Comment: попробуйте `pin_ptr<byte> pp = &input[0];` и использовать `pp` вместо `&input[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @VladD в итоге получилось вот так

```
    void Agent_CLI::CopyToArray([Out] array<unsigned char> ^% input)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned char> data = { 1, 1, 1, 0 };
        void * data_to_copy = data.data(); 

        int data_size = (int)data.size();
        input = gcnew array<unsigned char>(data_size);

        pin_ptr<unsigned char> p = &input[0]; 
        unsigned char * cp = p;

        memcpy(cp, data_to_copy, data_size * sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
```